# impress.js - bulleted list

Tags: javascript, css, impress.js

I have a question concerning impress.js. I wanted to use a bulleted list inside a div element of the class "step slide", however I am not able to do this.

Is this not possible or if it is: could you point me to the mistake I am making? The code I use is:

```
<div class="step slide" data-x="0" data-y="-1500">
    <q>aaa</q>
    <ul>
        <li>aaa</li>
        <li>aaa</li>
        <li>aaa</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The text is appearing but not as list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your div doesn't have a class of step slide, it has a class of step and a class of slide - to make it one class, just make them together:

```
<div class="stepslide">
<div class="step-slide">
<div class="step_slide">
```

Probably some style is overwriting the `ul`, try adding this in your `head` tag:

```
<style>
    .stepslide ul{
        list-style-type: bullet !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a mistake in the CSS stylesheet that I created for the presentation...but thanks a lot for pointing me to the class-issue.

Comment: @Nicole Accept answer please? Thanks